# vscode ignores type declarations until I navigate to a .d.ts file and save it

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

Just as the title says, vscode ignores type declarations until I navigate to a .d.ts file and save them. This is really annoying as it takes away a lot of the tools that come as a perk of adopting typescript with vscode such as go to definition, etc. Below is my tsconfig.json. My cra project and vscode are both using typescript@^4.3.5. I have seen other posts with similar issues but I am unable to find a resolution. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts"
  ],
}
```

Comment: I've had this happen multiple times.  the best thing to do in those events is to make sure you opened the project but its root - and open and close visual studio - sometimes its super buggy.  or you will end up saving sometimes hundreds of files depending on how large your project is and the amount of libraries you are importing.

Comment: if you have a Mac - I find just force quitting it seems to work the best, this may get a down vote but I searched in the past myself and have not found any solid work around - I am hoping someone answers you with one themselves.  this is also not specific to react because we do a ton of angular.

Comment: Thanks, still have yet to find a legitimate solution, hopefully someone else will see this and provide one.